# 8284 Clock Generator Output wave

Tags: oscilloscope, clock, microprocessor

I am attempting to build my very own 8086 computer. (I know, awesome right?) But not to confuse you, this post focuses only on the 8284A. We have started to cover the Intel 8086 chip in my microprocessor class but unfortunately the class only covers textbook and Assembly stuff, not the actual hands on hardware.

I thought the systems clock would be a good place to start. After all without a good clock the processor is wasted. I purchased a handful of 8284As and a 15MHz crystal to use with the [x1 and x2 outputs](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/124124/INTEL/8284A.html). I have put together my test circuit and it is shown below.

[image]

The wave output from the CLK pin looks like this:

[image]

Based on the datasheet for this chip the clk output is suppose to be 5Mhz with a 33% duty cycle. The output is extremely close to 5Mhz. The time division knob is set to .1us. The voltage is also consistent. However, it looks like the capacitors are discharging too soon. It's no where close to a square wave! My guess is bigger capacitors on the x1 pin. Any suggestions?

As always, thanks for your help.

Comment: The datasheet link says "Your require pages is cannot open by blow" :-)

Comment: @stevenvh Hahaha that's quite the error msg! I added a new link. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: What's with the three caps at the left? Are they 1nF or 10 pF??

Comment: @stevenvh They are 10pF. I didn't even notice that! That's sloppy (and PSPICE) for you. I will fix this as well.

Comment: Seriously, you need to go back and fix all the typos in your part numbers. Are you really using the 8060 chip (a.k.a. SC/MP from National Semiconductor)? Or are you using the 8086, the Intel chip normally driven by an 8284 (not 8486 as shown in your schematic)?

Comment: Did you adjust you probe recently?

Comment: @Dave - Don't say you remember SC/MP!! Gee, you're old :-)

Comment: @jippie It's been about 9 months since my last calibration.

Comment: are you referring scope calibration or probe calibration? The first one gets you a nice sticker (and a bill) from a company that does just that for you, the second one you do yourself on the probe.

Comment: @jippie Ohhh, I was referring to the probe. The scope is very old, but has always pulled through, it is a Tektronix 465B. I can't locate a sticker on it. But if I remember correctly it was serviced within the last few years.

Comment: I'd start by checking if your probe needs adjustment. Do you get a nice square wave when you connect your probes to the CAL output on your scope?

Comment: @jippie Yes, the calibration wave is as perfect as it can get. 300mV at 1KHz. I could always grab a digital scope from my lab and give it a try. Might be a couple of days before you here back though!!

Comment: Why are C6 and C7 connected anyway?

Comment: @stevenvh: Remember it? I've got one in a drawer around here somewhere! :-) (I'm 53, and I started messing around with embedded microprocessors in 1976, writing a real-time application for the 8008.)

Comment: @jippie I needed to cut their value in half! I didn't have a 100pF cap.

Answer (score 1):

The 100 pF load on the CLK signal shown in the data sheet is a test load used to verify worst-case timing. You don't need to have it in your circuit, and the waveform will probably look a lot better without it.

But actually, given that load, that waveform looks fine. Those old clock drivers didn't produce particularly "square" waves — and in fact, you wouldn't want them to, because it would just add to EMI and other bad effects. The key things are that the edges are monotonic (no glitches or "hooks" near the logic thresholds) and that the spacing of the crossings (about halfway between the peaks, third line down on the 'scope graticule) has the right timing (frequency and duty cycle), which it does.

BTW, your reset wiring is incorrect. R4, C5 and U1 should connect to the RES- pin, which is an input. The RESET pin is an output intended to drive the CPU's reset input.

Also, the PCLK pin is an output, and should *not* be tied to Vcc. Just leave it open if you're not using it.